# Using rdgal on R- error- No GDAL installation found

Tags: gdal, r, error, rgdal

I trying to map burnt area using hdf data. For this i have all the neccessary packages, including the rdgal pacakge.

However when i type in my burnt area code, i get the response [image]

I have downloaded rgdal as it is the R version of gdal, and apparently should work fine, however i cant seem to get rid of this error.
I have tried downloaded the gdal_setInstallation but again get errors saying it cannot find the function.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: rgdal, to my knowledge, doesn't install gdal, apparently you are in windows, you can install with osgeo4w https://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/osgeo4w-setup-x86_64.exe

Comment: that is surely the gdalUtils package, not rgdal - still, it'll be hard to read subdatasets with rgdal alone - will probalby need more detail to pursue this

Comment: I'm actually on a mac. im following the method from https://rdrr.io/github/ecmwf/caliver/man/get_gfed4.html for reading burnt area. I think there is something wrong with my caliver pacakge.